# Calabash can't connect to simulator

Tags: ios, cucumber, calabash

I'm trying to run some Calabash UI tests in my app but am running into trouble connecting to my simulator. I'm trying to just connect view the calabash-ios console, but am running into the following error:

```
 WARNING

Warning Trying to connect to simulator that was not launched by Calabash/instruments.
To fix this you must let Calabash or instruments launch the app.
Query will work, but gestures will not.
```

I've run the app view my -cal target and have successfully seen the message `Started LPHTTP server on port 37265`. Here's some more info on Calabash/my setup:

```
xcode-select --print-path
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

xcodebuild -version
Xcode 7.0
Build version 7A218

calabash-ios version
0.14.3

server_version
=> {"app_id"=>"com.solstice.discoverfinancialenterprise.mobile", "outcome"=>"SUCCESS", "server_port"=>37265, "version"=>"0.14.3", "app_name"=>"Discover", "system"=>"x86_64", "simulator_device"=>"iPhone", "simulator"=>"", "app_version"=>"1", "short_version_string"=>"6.6.1 UAT", "iphone_app_emulated_on_ipad"=>false, "app_base_sdk"=>"iphonesimulator9.0", "form_factor"=>"iphone 4in", "git"=>{"revision"=>"c2d009b", "remote_origin"=>"git@github.com:calabash/calabash-ios-server.git", "branch"=>"master"}, "screen_dimensions"=>{"sample"=>1, "height"=>1136, "width"=>640, "scale"=>2}, "4inch"=>true, "iOS_version"=>"8.4"}
```

Sorry the JSON isn't formatted, my console spat it out in an unformatted way.

I've used a few different simulators, iPhone 6, iOS 9 and iOS 8.3, and an iPhone 5s iOS 8.4. Does anyone know anything I need to do differently to get this to connect to my simulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+100 for including all the information about your environment.

Please update to Calabash 0.16.4 which is compatible with your Xcode version.

> I'm trying to just connect view the calabash-ios console, but am running into the following error:

Can you show how you launched console and what command you tried to run?

Typically, you want something like this:

```
$ APP=/path/to/Your.app calabash-ios console
> start_test_server_in_background
```

You must let calabash launch the app or you will not be able to perform gestures.

APP and APP_BUNDLE_PATH are synonymous.

http://calabashapi.xamarin.com/ios/file.ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLES.html#label-APP+and+APP_BUNDLE_PATH

Comment: That got it working on the server! OK, awesome, so I'm up and running on the server, I only set the DEVICE_TARGET variable, but not the APP variable... Although I may have tried setting APP_BUNDLE_PATH and it didn't work? Not sure, that's neither here nor there anymore. Now to try and tackle getting my feature scripts up and running.

Comment: APP and APP_BUNDLE_PATH are synonymous.